# How do I fix "Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined"?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

When I run this code, in Google Chrome, it gives me the following error:

> **Uncaught ReferenceError**: `FB` is not defined

I have read multiple other questions regarding the same error but none seem to have a solution for this.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    autoLogAppEvents : true,
    xfbml : true,
    version : 'v3.2'
  });
};

(function(d, s, id){
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

 FB.api(
   '/me',
   'GET',
   {"fields":"id,name,posts{picture,message,comments{likes}}"},
   function(response) {
       // Insert your code here
   }
 );
```

I want the Facebook API to return the fields I have selected.

My code is a copy of the code shown in Facebook's documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use FB before the JS SDK is initialized:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    autoLogAppEvents : true,
    xfbml : true,
    version : 'v3.2'
  });

  FB.api(
   '/me',
   'GET',
   {"fields":"id,name,posts{picture,message,comments{likes}}"},
   function(response) {
       console.log(response);
   }
  );
};

(function(d, s, id){
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

**Btw, this code will not work without user authorization. How to do that is explained in detail here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/**

**There is also a full example in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/#example**

Comment: I maight have missunderstood the functionality of this but this code doesn't return anything. As I specified in my question, I want code that returns the fields I have entred.

Comment: it does not "return" anything, those are asynchronous functions/callbacks. i will add a console.log in the answer, i hope it´s clear then.

Comment: btw, this does not make any sense without user authorization, i hope you know that. if not, you should read this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/

Comment: The console.log did indeed make the answer much clearer. And yes I am aware of the needed authorization.Thank you!